# Which service should I implement if I want it to do each 5 seconds one same work?

Tags: java, android, android-intent, service, android-intentservice

I am new to Android and I am implementing one chat application. I want to create a service which will send one message each 5 seconds to the chat so I can test receiving messages.

I am not sure which service should I implement. I am reading about binded and started, and about Service and IntentService classes.
Should I make a separate thread where I could sleep for 5 seconds and run in a loop the same sending message work? I understood that I should in onCreate() method initialize things for sending messages, but I am not sure if I should implement loop in onStartCommand() or somewhere else?
I want the service to send always messages so started service should be choosen,right?

Can someone tell me a little bit more about what should I use and why.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Perform a network task every 5 seconds? Forget about it. First of, its a very very bad practise. Second, at max you'd be able to go around 15 minutes with `WorkManager` & that too isn't exact. AlarmManager maybe okay for 'exactness' but never for this type of task. Atlast, you can use a `Foreground Service`.

Comment: @DarShan it is not network, it is sending a message to database. 5 seconds is for testing... to make like someone is really chatting and sending messages so I need to respond

Comment: If you want to make it look as if someone is chatting, add items to your `RecyclerView` or relevant `View` after every X seconds, adding items to a database is also an expensive operation even if 5 seconds is for testing.

Comment: @DarShan I am using chat sdk so I have there database and I want those messages to be saved when I open the app again